# Flask creating a unique profile page for each user

Tags: python, flask

I would like to create a unique profile page for each registered user on my website using Flask.  Currently, my code for the profile page is this:

```
@app.route('/profile/')
def profile():

if 'email' not in session:
    return redirect(url_for('signin'))

user = User.query.filter_by(email = session['email']).first()

if user is None:
    return redirect(url_for('signin'))
else:
    return render_template('profile.html')
```

However, when I try to change

```
@app.route('/profile/<lastname>')
def profile(lastname):
```

I get a werkzeug.routing.BuildError.  My question is, am I on the right track towards creating a unique profile page for each user, and if so, how can I add variables to my url so that I do not get a BuildError?  Thank you for your help.

Here is the full routes.py code:

```
from intro_to_flask import app
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, session, redirect, url_for
from forms import ContactForm, SignupForm, SigninForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
from models import db, User

mail = Mail()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit() == False:
            return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
        else:        
            name = request.form['name']
            subject = request.form['subject']
            senderEmail = request.form['email']
            message = request.form['message']
            msg = Message(subject, sender = senderEmail, recipients=    ['myemailaddress@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = message + "\n\n" + name + " (" + senderEmail + ")"
        mail.send(msg)
        return render_template('contact.html', success=True)

elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()    

    if 'email' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return render_template('signup.html', form = form)
        else:
            newuser = User(form.firstname.data, form.lastname.data, form.email.data,  form.password.data)
            db.session.add(newuser)
            db.session.commit()

            session['email'] = newuser.email

            return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html', form = form)

@app.route('/profile/')
def profile():

    if 'email' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))

    user = User.query.filter_by(email = session['email']).first()

    if user is None:
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    else:
        return render_template('profile.html')

@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    form = SigninForm()    

    if 'email' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return render_template('signin.html', form=form)
        else:
            session['email'] = form.email.data
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signin.html', form = form) 

@app.route('/signout')
def signout():

    if 'email' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))

    session.pop('email', None)
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I believe the BuildError is coming from the fact that I call url_for('profile') but my profile function takes in lastname as a parameter and it is not reflected in my url_for command.  I am just unsure what parameter I should include into my url_for method.

This is the code for my models.py:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(54))    

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password):
        self.firstname = firstname.title()
        self.lastname = lastname.title()
        self.email = email.lower()
        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you are showing, you must have a `url_for()` call somewhere where you forgot to add the `lastname` argument.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 **big** problems here:

1. Authentication
2. Url Routing

#### Authentication

You are doing it wrong. Why storing an email address in session and accessing it every time in the functions?
I suggest you to use a flask extension called [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org).
It handles everything for you and exposes a `current_user` proxy for your loggedin user.

For a reference implementation just follow the tutorial on the official site or take a look at [this Flask mini framework](https://bitbucket.org/xcash/flask-atuin).

#### URL Routing

You defined:

```
@app.route('/profile/<lastname>')
def profile(lastname):
```

So `lastname` is a mandatory argument. You need to call it in this way:

```
url_for('.profile', lastname='foo')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  When I change my code to url_for('.profile', lastname='foo'), my url becomes: localhost:5000/profile/foo.  Instead of foo being in the URL, I would like the user's actual last name.

Comment: @user3016362 yes, you need to substitute `foo` (it's a placeholder) with your lastname variable. Something like `user.last_name`. It really depends on the `user` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your decorator for the profile route and make it dynamic: from `@app.route('/profile/')` to `@app.route('/profile/<lastname>')` then fetch the last name from the database `db`, and specifically from the `User` table. Finally the returned profile page should also include the `lastname` variable.
The entire code for the profile page is show below.

```
from intro_to_flask import app
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, session, redirect, url_for
from forms import ContactForm, SignupForm, SigninForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
from models import db, User

mail = Mail()


# The rest of your routes



@app.route('/profile/<lastname>')
def profile(lastname):
    profile = User.query.filter_by(lastname=lastname).first()
    if profile is None:
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    else:
        return render_template('profile.html', lastname=lastname)
```